# Drop down menu and visualization

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to to add a drop-down box menu in which i will make my choice in order to visualize data. My visualization works fine without the drop-down box but when i put them together something goes wrong. In my code i want to visualize the data when i choose selection02. Could anyone help me?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function allagi()
{
   if (document.getElementById("selection01").selected==true)
   {
      function01();
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection02").selected==true)
   {
      f1();
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection03").selected==true)
   {
      function03();
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection04").selected==true)
   {
      function04();
   }
}


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> 
function f1(){
 {"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AihqKzH-MgAndERnaFVsYk1RLUM3S0pDSmNjcEQ4M1E&transpose=0&headers=0&range=A2%3AB13&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}}],"booleanRole":"certainty","animation":{"duration":0},"useFirstColumnAsDomain":true,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},"isStacked":false,"width":454,"height":285},"state":{},"chartType":"AreaChart","chartName":"\u0393\u03c1\u03ac\u03c6\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 1"} 
 }
 </script>



</head>
<body>



<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo"><select onchange="allagi()">
  <option id="selection01">Selection01</option>
  <option id="selection02">Selection02</option>
  <option id="selection03">Selection03</option>
  <option id="selection04">Selection04</option>
</select></div>
  <div id="pie">






  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try passing value instead of using id

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle example (Without the selection)?
You function f1 looks invalid to me. I don't think you can have nested braces without a qualifier statement

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function allagi() {
    if (document.getElementById("d4ropdown1").value == "s1" )
   {
    alert ("1");
   }
 else if (document.getElementById("selection02").value == "s2")
  {
   document.getElementById("VisualizationDisplay").style.display = "block";
   }
  else if (document.getElementById("selection03").value == "s3")
  {
   alert("3");
  }
  else if (document.getElementById("selection04").value == "s4")
  {
   alert("4");
  }
  }
</script>


<div id="VisualizationDisplay" style="display:none">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js">
 {"dataSourceUrl":"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AihqKzH-MgAndERnaFVsYk1RLUM3S0pDSmNjcEQ4M1E&   transpose=0&headers=0&range=A2%3AB13&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}}],"booleanRole":"certainty","animation":{"duration":0},"useFirstColumnAsDomain":true,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},"isStacked":false,"width":454,"height":285},"state":{},"chartType":"AreaChart","chartName":"\u0393\u03c1\u03ac\u03c6\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 1"} </script>

</div>
 <div id="logo"><select id="d4ropdown1" onchange="allagi()">
 <option id="selection01" value="s1">Selection01</option>
 <option id="selection02" value="s2">Selection02</option>
 <option id="selection03" value="s3">Selection03</option>
 <option id="selection04" value="s4">Selection04</option>
</select></div>
```

This is just an hack ... it works as you want it...but I am sure there should be a better way of doing it..sorry if I wasn't helpful...

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but my problem is that i can't visualize my data. I can't link my first script(drop down box) with the second (visualization) because they have different src.

Comment: yes there is an error but i can't find it. Nevertheless the visualization works fine.

Comment: are you able to see visualization if you just convert the body onload to f1()..bcoz I think something is wrong with the way that method is defined..

Comment: try https: see this post http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/spreadsheets/JVodH6TvPgQ

Comment: I have edited my answer can you try that...the function wont work in the google chart api

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the JavaScript you've written is syntactically invalid.

You've written `function f1() { "string" }` where "string" looks like a JSON string.  I think that you meant to write code that would invoke a function that would pass this string as a parameter, but I don't know the syntax of the service you're using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> 
function f1(){
 {"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AihqKzH-MgAndERnaFVsYk1RLUM3S0pDSmNjcEQ4M1E&transpose=0&headers=0&range=A2%3AB13&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}}],"booleanRole":"certainty","animation":{"duration":0},"useFirstColumnAsDomain":true,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},"isStacked":false,"width":454,"height":285},"state":{},"chartType":"AreaChart","chartName":"\u0393\u03c1\u03ac\u03c6\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 1"} 
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am trying to visualize my data by using a drop-down box. My visualization works fine but i can't put it in the drop down box.